# Where to put scroll to row code in swiftui list

Tags: swiftui, uiscrollview

I have a following code:

```swift
    ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            List{
                ForEach(viewModel.searchResults(of: searchText), id: \.0) { item in
                    Section {
                        ForEach(item.1, id: \.id) { match in
                            MatchListCell(condensedVersion: true, match: match)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    print(match.debugDescription)
                                }
                        }
                        
                    } header: {
                        Text(item.0.stringFromDate())
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            .bold()
                    }
                }
                .onAppear{
                    var scrollToId = Date()
                    
                    for date in viewModel.allMatchDates.sorted() {
                        if date > Date.now {
                            scrollToId = date
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    proxy.scrollTo(scrollToId, anchor: .top)
                }
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText)          
        }
```

It produces a list of matches, sorted by date and after loading of new data it scrolls to upcoming matches. I believe putting the code into onAppear function is not correct, because it's called when manually scrolling data as well which makes it unusable. But where should I put it?

Comment: On the `List` probably generally you shouldn't attach anything to a `ForEach`